# rel="external", PHP in jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile to make a web app, but many pages would be .php files. I have to use rel="external" in  tag directed to those php files, otherwise the link would be "undefined". 
The problem is then I have to load jQuery scripts for every .php pages I have (since I want the JQM layout). What could be the way out if I don't want to download the js files again every time I reach a .php page?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with using PHP files as long as they are created using proper HTML syntax. Can you show an example of the links you're working with?

Comment: For example, in index.html I got a link <a href="gallery.php rel="external"> The link would show "undefined" unless I add rel="external".

Comment: Jasper you are right, as I later on succeed in loading the php without rel="external", with correct jQuery layout. I think one of the plugin I used need rel="external" that complicated the matter. However I do wonder had I load all the css and js script in the index page, is it the case that those resources would follow to all subsequent pages (if they load properly)?qq

Comment: OK the problem is: my index page led to upload.php, with a sumbit button submitting a photo to the server, however the submission wouldn't work unless I use rel="external"  for upload.php...

Answer (score 1):

Call js files static named. I mean, let browser caches it don't suffer yourself.

**Answer to your comment :**

> You have to do "leverage browser caching". Here is the explaination :
>
> http://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching
>
> after that, your js files src's have to exactly same every page.
>
> I mean, if you are calling x.js file on a.php with "**src='js/x.js'**" then call it on b.php same with "**src='js/x.js'**".
>
> If you are still developing or you'll develop js files, there must be version numbers when calling them. Because with leverage browser caching, you will say "this file will expire next year". So, when you develop, new developed js will not downloaded by user if he don't forces it. You can call js files with version numbers like this "**src='js/x.js?v=0.0.1'**"
>
> You can easily test your page's cache with this tool : http://tools.pingdom.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, but I am really not familiar with caching. I had thought about loading all the js scripts on the index page, but I can't figure out what the script src would be for subsequent pages. I would appreciate a lot if you can illuminate me.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. I read that one had to  do it through server http headers... or just add this <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">...                     As my app is intended to be a web app, I also saw the suggestion to reduce header request as much as possible, and use local storage instead... I am really newbie into this and which method is really the best?

Comment: Actually I don't even understand what they are talking about but I don't think so your header is very big or can get very big. By the way doing cache with server http headers is more useful. And use gzip also.